# Push Notification with Big Image Not automatically expand on Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge (Android)

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

i want to know why **Push Notification with Big Image** on **Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge** is not Expanding automatically? We need to click then it Expands. We want to have Auto Expand behavior of Push Notifications. I want to know that is it something with Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge theme issue or by Programatically something is missing? but one thing should be keep in mind this App already Showing Expanded Push Notification with Image on all other Devices.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out about this?